# Understanding dask array chunks

Tags: arrays, dask

I am trying to learn how array chunking works by reading the docs [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-chunks.html#chunks-examples).

Below is an output from a Python session where I try to reproduce the examples.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: npa = np.array([
   ...: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   ...: [7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
   ...: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
   ...: [9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
   ...: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
   ...: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   ...: ])

In [3]: import dask.array as da

In [4]: a = da.from_array(npa, chunks=3)

In [5]: a
Out[5]: dask.array<array, shape=(6, 6), dtype=int64, chunksize=(3, 3), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

I would expect each chunk(/block?) of `a` to have shape `(3, 3)` since that is what I specified in the `chunks` parameter and what the example in the docs seems to suggest.

However, when I read out the first block, it has a shape of `(3, 6)`.

```
In [6]: a.blocks[0]
Out[6]: dask.array<blocks, shape=(3, 6), dtype=int64, chunksize=(3, 3), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

And, as expected given the shape, I can only read out two blocks. When I read out the third block an `IndexError` is raised.

```
In [7]: a.blocks[2]
...
IndexError: Index is not smaller than dimension 2 >= 2
```

I would expect there to be four 3x3 blocks, not two 3x6 blocks.

What am I not understanding about how array chunking works in dask?

Comment: Agreed, this does seem odd.  Maybe something has changed in https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/array/core.py#L2357 ?  I'd recommend filing an issue.  In the case you've outlined above dask builds two arrays of (3,6) which is strange given the docs

Comment: Thanks @joshreback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6468#issuecomment-666645836).

> Your chunks/blocks are in two dimensions, so you can index them in two dimensions